# Package Manager Console prompt is messed up after installing oh-my-posh

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, posh-git, oh-my-posh

I have oh-my-posh and posh-git installed and added to my Powershell profile, which looks like this

```
Import-Module posh-git
Import-Module oh-my-posh
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config "$env:POSH_THEMES_PATH\thecyberden.omp.json" | Invoke-Expression
```

I'm using the CaskaydiaCove NF font in Powershell, which I also set as the font for the Package Manager Console.

[image]

My Windows Terminal prompt is correct:

[image]

However, the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio is weird, like it's not able to find the correct glyphs:

[image]

Is there a way to fix my Package Manager Console prompt so that either it displays correctly like Powershell, or so that it ignores the Powershell profile and just uses its default prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, its already some time since problem was reported. I had same issue and found a workaround. I changed my Profile.ps1 like this:

```
$vsprofile = oh-my-posh get shell
if ($vsprofile -ne "devenv") {
  oh-my-posh init pwsh | Invoke-Expression
  Import-Module -Name Terminal-Icons  
}
```

It may be thats an ugly hack, but provides oh-my-posh via Windows Terminal and prevents it in Visual Studio Package. However as soon as Visual Studio is lauched, ist seems that the Environment Variable is set system wide and thus all pwsh started after VS don't get oh-my-posh activated.

Comment: Wow, thank you.  This worked to make my Package Manager prompt correct.  In my case, my Windows Terminal Powershell prompts still had the oh-my-posh styling even after I opened Visual Studio.

Comment: Improved the anwser ...

Answer (score 1):

This is because that shell doesn't support ANSI. Have a look at the [PowerShell settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals?view=powershell-7.2) in case this is 7, otherwise there's no fix for it.

Comment: Yes I know. therefore I was looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio use their own font configuration for the Terminal. I've solve the problem by changing the font in Visual Studio Settings to use a Nerd Font:

Go to **Options**/**Fonts and Colors**, select **Terminal** in **Show Setting For** combo and choose a Nerd Font from **Font** Combo.

[image]